# Trouble freeing all memory in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, huffman-code

I'm huffman encoding an array of integers using a minheap. My issue is freeing the MinHeap and MinHeapNodes once I've printed the huffman codes to the screen. Whenever I call "printCodes" I'm freeing the leafs of the minHeap, but I am still having trouble freeing the non-leaf nodes as well as the MinHeap and the MinHeap's array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_TREE_HT 100

struct MinHeapNode {
        int data;
        unsigned freq;
        struct MinHeapNode *left, *right;
};

struct MinHeap {
        unsigned size;
        unsigned capacity;
        struct MinHeapNode **array;
};

struct MinHeapNode *newNode(int data, unsigned freq) {
        struct MinHeapNode *temp = (struct MinHeapNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeapNode));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = data;
        temp->freq = freq;
        return temp;
}

struct MinHeap *createMinHeap(unsigned capacity) {
        struct MinHeap *minHeap = (struct MinHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));
        minHeap->size = 0;
        minHeap->capacity = capacity;
        minHeap->array = (struct MinHeapNode**)malloc(minHeap->capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*));
        return minHeap;
}

void swapMinHeapNode(struct MinHeapNode **a, struct MinHeapNode **b) {
        struct MinHeapNode *tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
}
void minHeapify(struct MinHeap *minHeap, int index) {
        int smallest = index;
        int left = 2 * index + 1;
        int right = 2 * index + 2;

        if (left < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[left]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
                smallest = left;
        if (right < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[right]->freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
                smallest = right;
        if (smallest != index) {
                swapMinHeapNode(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[index]);
                minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
        }
}
int isSizeOne(struct MinHeap *minHeap) {
        return (minHeap->size == 1);
}
struct MinHeapNode *extractMin(struct MinHeap *minHeap) {
        struct MinHeapNode *temp = minHeap->array[0];
        minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1];
        --minHeap->size;
        minHeapify(minHeap, 0);
        return temp;
}

void insertMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap, struct MinHeapNode *minHeapNode) {
        ++minHeap->size;
        int i = minHeap->size - 1;
        while (i && minHeapNode->freq < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->freq) {
                minHeap->array[i] = minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2];
                i = (i - 1) / 2;
        }
        minHeap->array[i] = minHeapNode;
}
void buildMinHeap(struct MinHeap *minHeap) {
        int n = minHeap->size - 1;
        int i;
        for (i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
                minHeapify(minHeap, i);
}
void printArr(int arr[], int n) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                printf("%d", arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
}
int isLeaf(struct MinHeapNode *root) {
        return !(root->left) && !(root->right);
}

struct MinHeap *createAndBuildMinHeap(int data[], int freq[], int size) {
        struct MinHeap *minHeap = createMinHeap(size);
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                minHeap->array[i] = newNode(data[i], freq[i]);
        minHeap->size = size;
        buildMinHeap(minHeap);
        return minHeap;
}

struct MinHeapNode *buildHuffmanTree(int data[], int freq[], int size, struct MinHeap *clear) {
        struct MinHeapNode *left, *right, *top;
        struct MinHeap *minHeap = createAndBuildMinHeap(data, freq, size);
        while (!isSizeOne(minHeap)) {
                left = extractMin(minHeap);
                right = extractMin(minHeap);
                top = newNode(255, left->freq + right->freq);
                top->left = left;
                top->right = right;
                insertMinHeap(minHeap, top);
        }
        clear = minHeap;
        //clear->array = minHeap->array
        return extractMin(minHeap);
}
void printCodes(struct MinHeapNode *root, int arr[], int top) {
        if (root->left) {
                arr[top] = 0;
                printCodes(root->left, arr, top + 1);
        }
        if (root->right) {
                arr[top] = 1;
                printCodes(root->right, arr, top + 1);
        }
        if (isLeaf(root)) {
                printf("%d: ", root->data);
                printArr(arr, top);
                free(root);
        }
}
void HuffmanCodes(int data[], int freq[], int size) {
        struct MinHeap *clear;
        struct MinHeapNode *root = buildHuffmanTree(data, freq, size, clear);
        int arr[MAX_TREE_HT], top = 0;
        printCodes(root, arr, top);
        //free(clear->array); Adding this will crash the program
        //free(clear);
        free(root);
}
int main() {
        int arr[] = {3, 4, 5};
        int freq[] = {1, 4, 5};
        int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
        HuffmanCodes(arr, freq, size);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: UPDATE: I moved "free(root);" to the bottom of the printCodes function which was able to free all allocated MinHeapNodes, but I'm still having trouble freeing the MinHeap and it's array, as seen in the function "createMinHeap".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would rename your **printCodes** function **printCodesAndFree** for readability.
2. I'm guessing, you're gonna scratch your head and then bang it against the wall. You're passing the **clear** pointer by value to **createAndBuildMinHeap** and set the local variable. You should pass **&clear** instead and receive the argument struct MinHeap** clear in **buildHuffmanTree**, then set ***clear = minHeap**. I suspect this would solve your issues.

Comment: That did the trick! I completely overlooked that. I've been banging my head against the wall for a bit over such a simple fix. Thank you!